# How to get GPU information from multiple EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

So I have multiple shared EC2 instances with GPUs used by a team, I want to create a streamlined process for checking which machine has free GPUs. I use ssh to access the instances and can find the relevant GPU information using

```
nvidia-smi
```

However, since I have no experience here, how can I go about developing a way to check free GPUs in a given list of instances. So far I can think of only ssh-ing into each and getting and returning information in one place, but would like a better way to do it.

Comment: Do you use an existing metric based monitoring system? This sounds like something you could publish as a metric to something like cloudwatch or prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure all your instances to be managed by AWS Systems Manager (SSM) and this will allow you to run commands on a fleet of instances using the SSM Document `AWS-RunShellScript`. SSM allows you to remotely execute shell commands on managed instances without having to manually log in and execute the way you would with SSH. [This doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-cli.html#walkthrough-cli-example-3) should get you started.

You might also wanna look into [SSM Automation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-automation.html).